# Wireshark Kerberos decrypt shows error "missing keytype 18"

Tags: windows, security, kerberos, wireshark-dissector

When trying to decrypt the kerberos by using the keytab file it shows the error "missing keytype 18". The keytab file has the keytype 18.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please be elaborative while putting a question. Please tell us what is the setup and tool you are using. Can you provide the stacktrace or complete error log that you are getting?

Comment: We are using Wireshark Version 3.4.8. The Wireshark filter is kerberos. The keytab file is specified in KRB5 protocol preference. Keytab file has the encryption type eTYPE-AES256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96(18). But while monitoring the Kerberos traffic "missing keytype 18" error shows. It seems wireshark not using the Keytab file. Please help.

Comment: Can you please paste the entries from your keytab (SPNs mainly) and which SPN your app is using?

Comment: SPN: HOST/INTVMDC03.xxxx.com/xxxx.com. Keytab created using the java ktab utility.
Key tab entries:
KVNO Principal
---- ------------------------------------------------------------------
1 1013219@xxxx.com (18:AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96)
1 1013219@xxxx.com (17:AES128 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96)
1 1013219@xxxx.com (20:AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA384-192)
1 1013219@xxxx.com (19:AES128 CTS mode with HMAC SHA256-128)
1 1013219@xxxx.com (16:DES3 CBC mode with SHA1-KD)
1 1013219@xxxx.com (23:RC4 with HMAC)

Comment: keytab file created with the user principal. Is the service principal required? Is it possible with java ktab? If yes, how? Else, could you suggest any tool for win-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you shared:

> SPN: HOST/INTVMDC03.xxxx.com/xxxx.com.
>
> Keytab entries:
> 1 1013219@xxxx.com (18:AES256 CTS mode with HMAC
> SHA1-96)
>   1 1013219@xxxx.com (17:AES128 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96)
>  1
> 1013219@xxxx.com (20:AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA384-192)
>  1
> 1013219@xxxx.com (19:AES128 CTS mode with HMAC SHA256-128)
>  1
> 1013219@xxxx.com (16:DES3 CBC mode with SHA1-KD)
>  1 1013219@xxxx.com
> (23:RC4 with HMAC)

There is no entry corresponding to the SPN being used inside your keytab.
What you need is SPN entries inside keytab, not the UPN entries.
Remember that the ticket is issued for the SPN and not the user principal name (UPN). Therefore Kerberos looks for the SPN entry inside keytab for which the ticket is issued.
Please generate a new keytab file and provide SPN.
For windows, you can use `ktpass` command (usually works on windows server os).
[Check Here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ktpass)

For example:

```
ktpass /out <filename> /princ <ServicePrincipalName> /mapuser <UserPrincipalName> /pass <UPN password> /crypto ALL /ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL /kvno 0
```

Comment: Thank you. Is UPN mandatory in the key tab file? What is the tool and command for create a kebtab equallent to ktpass with SPN and UPN?

Comment: UPN is not necessary in the keytab. As I mentioned, the ticket is issued for the SPN - means the ticket is encrypted with the key (assume password) of the SPN. Therefore SPN and its corresponding key is what you need in keytab.